# EDIT: Solve the second-order ODE $y''+\frac{1}{x}y'=a,\;a$ constant using variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Note: I changed $y$ to $y'$. Solve the second-order ODE $y''+\frac{1}{x}y'=a,\;\;a$ constant.

For me to use Variation of parameters, I need to find two linearly independent solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$, where the particular solution, $y_p$ is given by

\begin{align} y_p(x)=-y_1(x)\int\dfrac{r(x)y_2(x)}{W(y_1,y_2)}dx+y_2(x)\int\dfrac{r(x)y_1(x)}{W(y_1,y_2)}dx  \end{align}
and $W,\;r(x)$ are Wronskian and the right-hand side, respectively. Here, $r(x)=a.$

So, I need to look for the solution to $y''+\frac{1}{x}y'=0$ to get $y_1$ and $y_2.$ If I get them, I'm done. Is there any way of getting these two?

Comment: WA says this here $$\left\{\left\{y(x)\to -\pi  a J_1\left(2
   \sqrt{x}\right) G_{2,4}^{2,1}\left(x\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{3}{2},1 \\
 \frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{2},\frac{1}{2},1 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)+\pi  a x^{5/2} \, _0\tilde{F}_1(;3;-x)
   Y_1\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)+c_1 \sqrt{x} J_1\left(2
   \sqrt{x}\right)+2 i c_2 \sqrt{x} Y_1\left(2
   \sqrt{x}\right)\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: Wow! That's something else!

Comment: $y_1=ax$ works. I don't know how to go about finding a second linearly independent solution though.

Comment: Making $Y(x) = y(x) + ax$ you have the DE $Y''(x) + \frac 1x Y(x) = 0$ solving for $Y(x)$ we have then $y(x) = Y(x)-a x$

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: Sorry for the actual error, I made an edit!

Comment: @John Doe: Sorry for the actual error, I made an edit!

Comment: @Cesareo: Sorry for the actual error, I made an edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solvable.$$xy''+y'=0\\(xy')'=ax\\xy'=C_1\\y=\int\frac {C_1}x\,dx\\y=C_1\ln x+C_2$$
So your two independent solutions can be $1$ and $\ln x$.

Comment: @LutzL You're right, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate $xy''+y'=0$ to $xy'=C$ and further to $y=C\ln x+D$, which is the homogeneous or complimentary solution.